# Which technology is behind intel's realsense depth sensor?

Tags: intel, sensors, realsense

Which technology is behind intel's realsense depth sensor?

Is it a structured light or ToF approach?

Where can I find specs?

Comment: there are 3 variants

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least for the front-facing camera, it seems to be [structured light](http://www.chipworks.com/about-chipworks/overview/blog/inside-the-intel-realsense-gesture-camera).

Answer (score 2):

You might be able to find some more information on the [RealSense Website](https://software.intel.com/en-us/realsense/f200camera)

As far as specs go, this is all I could find:
Full VGA depth resolution
1080p RGB camera
0.2 – 1.2 meter range (Specific algorithms may have different range and accuracy)
USB 3.0 interface

Answer (score 1):

The IR Laser Projector on the Intel RealSense F200 camera sends non visible patterns (coded light) onto the object. The reflected patterns are captured by the IR camera and processed by the ASIC  which assigns depth values to each pixel to create a depth video frame.

Applications see 2 (depth and color) video streams.
The ASIC syncs depth with color stream (texture mapping) using UVC time stamp and generates data flags for each depth value (valid, invalid, or motion detected.)

Comment: Hi codecats, thank you for your answer. Do you have any reference on that?